# Sample data for MariaDB Knowledge Base?

Tags: mariadb

Following MariaDB Knowledge Base(kb), I'd like to hands-on query like:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/semi-join-materialization-strategy/

```sql
select * from Country 
where Country.code IN (select City.Country 
                       from City 
                       where City.Population > 7*1000*1000)
      and Country.continent='Europe'
```

Can I get the sample DB for that? I found some similars, but none of them are fit in exactly:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html (`world` and `world_x`)
- https://www.mariadbtutorial.com/getting-started/mariadb-sample-database/ (`nation`)

Answer (score 0):

[world db](https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world_x-db.tar.gz) work for queries with little modifying of the city's column name , `City.countryCode` over `City.countryCode`, in following KBs:

- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/semi-join-subquery-optimizations/
- https://mariadb.com/kb/en/semi-join-materialization-strategy/

It would be helpful to list other DBs for other KB queries executable.

+ Create the following index on `city` makes same results:

```sql
CREATE INDEX Population ON city (population);
```

Comment: MariaDB's kb is and editable document. You can edit pages once you have a basic login.

Comment: I didn't know that. But I have no certainty on the data, `world` DB I found, is for the queries in kb. No explanations about the DB on kb, and they, the `world` and the kb describing ,are seemed slightly different.